# how to post SQL variable through session and get it in next page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to post `$dataHeadArr` value through session and get it in next page.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{ $storename=$_POST["StoreName"];
    $dataHeadArr=$db->query("SELECT *FROM  `opening_stk`");?>
```

Comment: Google "php sessions tutorial"

Comment: store the value in session and in next page retrieve the value from session

Comment: *For the record:* You have a missing closing brace. This `}` is a (*closing*) brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On for the page you have posted put

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["search"])){
        session_start(); 
        $storename=$_POST["StoreName"];
        $dataHeadArr=$db->query("SELECT * FROM  `opening_stk`");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($dataHeadArr)){
           $allRows[]=$row;
        }
        $_SESSION['dataHeadArr']=$allRows;
    }

?>
```

For the page that you want to retreive the variable put

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $dataHeadArr=$_SESSION['dataHeadArr'];
   //This mysql result been parsed already, so you should be 
   //able to access values when you loop through it from here
   for($i=0;$i<count($dataHeadArr); $i++){
       echo "Printing row ".$i."</br>";
       foreach($dataHeadArr[$i] as $key=>$item){ 
            //Prints out all value for the row
            echo $item[$key]."</br>";
       }
       echo "</br>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: As, you suggested i did but when i call the function like this:` $res1=mysql_query($dataHeadArr)or die($dataHeadArr."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());` i am getting error 
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,Notice: Array to string conversion please give solution thanking you @ksealey

Comment: $dataHeadArr is the result you received from the first query. Are you passing this to mysql_fetch_assoc() or mysql_query() as you have just posted?

You should have something like
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($dataHeadArr)){
     //In here you can access the values returned from the query for each row
      foreach($row as $key=> $value){
          echo $value."<br/>";
      }
}

Comment: my actual sql query is `SELECT o.E_Date, h.Head_Name, s.Store_Name, g.G_Name, o.P_Code, o.Qty,  o.UName FROM  `opening_stk` o 
LEFT JOIN `store_mstr`  s on o.Store_Cd=s.ACode 
LEFT JOIN `godown_mstr` g on o.G_Cd    =g.ACode 
LEFT JOIN `head_mstr`   h on o.H_Cd    =h.ACode WHERE o.Store_Cd='$storename' this because of $storename i am getting error again if u can help me please @ksealey

Comment: What is your error? The same as before?

Comment: yes, same as abobe @ksealey

Comment: Hm. Not sure what's happening on you're end because I can't see all the code. Please use samples from the updated code I just posted and see if you can see your values. Also, have you pasted your query directly at your database to make sure you are receiving results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You may just set it in the POST or SESSION array and then retrieve it on next page. For ex-

```
$_POST['dataHeadArr']=$dataHeadArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

To store...

```
$_SESSION['dataHeadArr'] = 'Whatever';
```

Then to retrieve simply..

```
if(isset($_SESSION['dataHeadArr'])){
    echo $_SESSION['dataHeadArr'];
}
```

Make sure to call session_start(); at the top of every page.